# Struts 2 parameter coding problem during redirect to another action

Tags: java, struts2

I try to redirect to another action and to transmit a string parameter. This works without problems, but I have a coding problem if I am using german umlauts.

Here is my code:
First action has a field message with getter and setter. In the action I set the String.

```
private String message;
public String action1()
{
     message = "ö";
     return SUCCESS;
}
```

Second action has a field message with getter and setter too.

```
private String message;
```

Struts.xml with the definition of the both actions

```
<action name="action" method="action1" class="de.samba.control.actions.Action1">
<result name="success" type="redirectAction">
<param name="actionName">action2</param>
<param name="message">${message}</param>
```

```
<action name="action2" class="de.samba.control.actions.Action2">
<result name="success">/pages/showMessage.jsp</result>
```

If I don´t using redirection and show the message on a jsp, all works fine. The coding is correct.
If I redirect to another action the setter of the message field set the wrong formattet string "Ã¶".
I cannot found the solution. Can somebody help me please?

Own Filter:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>de.samba.control.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Filter-class

```
public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain next) throws IOException, ServletException 
{
    String encoding = request.getCharacterEncoding();
    if (encoding == null || encoding.length() == 0)
    {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    }
    encoding = request.getCharacterEncoding();
    next.doFilter(request, response); 
}
}
```

Then I tried this filter:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>
       <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
</filter>
```

This does not work too. Do somebody know this problem? Maybe it is caused by Spring Security.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was a tomcat issue and not a struts issue.
The solution is to set the URIEncoding of the Connector to "utf-8" in server.xml.
See http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/how-to-support-utf-8-uriencoding-with-tomcat.html

Comment: Hi Rafael., I facing the same problem (initially it was working fine in FF and not in IE), After I followed your solution, it works fine in IE, but it Doesn't work any more in FF, could you please help me to fix this.. its very very urgent.. thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is in the way the url (which makes action invocation) is generated. For instance, if the url generations is something like below, be aware of the [attribute escape](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8/docs/property.html) :

```
 <s:url namespace="/" action="recursoNuevo" var="recursoNuevo" >
   <s:param name="contextPath">
      <s:property value="contextPath" escape="false"/>
   </s:param>
  </s:url>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question looks like it is the same issue you are having:

[Struts2 request character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958797/struts2-request-character-encoding)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. This seemed to be the right solution. But it does not work. Trying this I have the impression that maybe not struts2 is debt, but Spring Security. Because I try it with an own Charakterencoding-Filter and with a org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter. Both solutions do not work. I write the Filter code to my question. Maybe I made mistakes.

Comment: This should not be the issue. When redirecting an action via redirectAction, I don't think  that the web.xml is considered, or Spring Security for that matter. My guess would be it has something to do with the interceptors that transfer the value from one action to the next. Maybe a bug?

Comment: According to http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/redirect-action-result.html, the redirectAction will "redirect the browser to a URL that invokes the specified action". If it is redirecting the browser, it is creating a brand new request rather than just going through interceptors, and it will go through the web.xml again.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you can try saving your message variable in session. moreover, afaik, generally speaking, in web application, the recommended way of passing information from 1 action to another action is by using session.

and if anything else fails, i guess there is a hackie way. you can release the result to an ordinary web page (jsp). you put that message value in an input element. then you write a javascript which automatically submit the value inside that input element. not recommended, though.

Comment: That's not true. A server-side redirect from one action to another should be possible, and if the first action requires you to get a message to the user, say if you have a userEnteredData.action that takes form data and puts it into a DB and a renderProfilePage.action that has some logic that you need to render a page, you should not need to use the session. Sessions are there for statekeeping between requests over a stateless protocol.