# How alt characters binds to bean object in struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am doing form validation in my struts2 application. In which user enters alt characters (for e.g. ®) in textbox. But whenever I am trying to check value of this value in formbean, this character is getting converted to � before binding.

In my jsp, i have set

```
contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
```

and

```
pageEncoding="UTF-8"
```

in <%@ page %> tag.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4814061/1700321.

Comment: And this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17409254/1654265

Comment: I went through both links and made changes in jsp as well as server.xml file. But it did not worked for me.

Comment: Show some code. How do you check values? Any js involved?

Comment: In server.xml :  `<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>`. In JSP : `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`. In Action : `private LoginBean loginBean = new LoginBean();
 
 public LoginBean getLoginBean() {
  return loginBean;
 }

 @Override
 public Object getModel() {
  return getLoginBean();
 }`. No js involved.